# How to copy a field in one record to another record using BeanIO

Tags: java, bean-io

Am trying to access the data for "accountNumber" field in record2 as a "property". File format is flat file (format="fixedlength"). Please help me on this.

```xml
<beanio xmlns="http://www.beanio.org/2012/03">
    <stream name="Definitions" format="fixedlength">
        <record name="header" order="1" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" class="map">
            <field name="recordType"  literal="HD" position="0" length="2" rid="true"/>
        </record>
        <group name="Sample" order="2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" class="map">
                <record name="record1" order="1" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"  class="map">
                    <field name="type" rid="true" literal="PP" position="0" length="2"/>
                    <field name="accountNumber" position="2" length="30"/>
                </record>
                <record name="record2" order="2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" class="map" collection="list" >
                    <field name="type" rid="true" literal="FF" position="0" length="2"/>
            < ******------ I want to access the "accountNumber" here ------****** />
                </record>
        </group>
        <record name="trailer" order="3" >
            <field name="recordType" rid="true" literal="TT" position="0" length="2"/>
        </record>  
    </stream>
</beanio>
```

Sample Data:

```
HD                                 
PPXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   
FF                                    
FF                                    
PPYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY                  
FF                                    
FF                                    
TT
```

Comment: Could you add an example of what your input file can look like?

Comment: This question is similar to: *"How do I use data in the header record in each detail record?"*

Comment: Hi Niel.. I have posted one example and thanks for your help.

Comment: Also am not able to see the suggested post "How do I use data in the header record in each detail record?". Could you please share the link.

Comment: Ram, it is not another question that can be linked, but it would be another way of stating the same problem because in bean-io a header is just another type of record.

Comment: Can you help me on my question. Is there a way to configure my requirment using beanio config file

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to do the combination yourself after reading all the records. This will be possible because the information from `record1` will exist in the map for the `Sample` group. You will have to iterate over each `record2` and set the information from `record1`.

---

I haven't fully implemented this yet, but I will soon, and here is my strategy using spring-batch:

- I don't group my records.
- Create different classes for the two records.
- Set up a batch job with the bean-io `ItemReader`.
- Add a `ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor` to the job with a `SubclassClassifier`.

  - The type map maps the two records' classes to specific `ItemProcessors`,
  - The `record1` `ItemProcessor` will add the information in that record to the step's `ExecutionContext` and return **null** to avoid the `ItemWriter` from being called.
- Add an `ItemWriter` to the job which will read the `ExecutionContext` and write the combination of `record1` with each `record2`.

I hope this helps.